# Can I put a condition for y-index in numpy.where?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array taken from a segmentation. Therefore, it's an image like the one in the right:

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwYeYOHk0xUJ6vBd_g8Xn1LxMON0g2qHpf_TPJx6h7IM5nG2OXeKtDuCcjgN9mqFtLB5c&usqp=CAU

The colours you see means that each value of my array can only have a value in a limit range (e.g., green is 5, orange is 7...). Now I would like to change all the cells that contains a 5 (green) and its y-coordinate is up to a value I want (e.g. only apply the later condition up to row 400). What's the most optimized algorithm to do this?

I guess that you can use something like:

```
np.where(myarray == 5, myarray, valueIwant)
```

but I will need to apply the condition for y-index...

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "for another value that at the same time, are for (x,y) where y>half of the height of my image" ?? Please, use better English

Comment: you can find examples how `np.where` works here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: Please, instead of providing all the information about your general task, give a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So here, you could just give the input array and the output array you want, without any unnecessary information about image segmentation. This way, your question is more useful to the future readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current example seems to be misaligned with what you want:

```py
a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
np.where(a==2, a, 7)
```

produces:

```py
array([7, 7, 2, 2, 7, 7])
```

---

If you want to **replace 2** with some other value:

```py
array([1, 1, 7, 7, 3, 3])
```

you can do this:

```py
np.where(a==2, 7, a)
```

or

```py
a[a==2] = 7
```

---

### To replace only up to a certain value:

```py
sub_array = a[:3]

sub_array[sub_array==2] = 7
a
```

```
array([1, 1, 7, 2, 3, 3])
```

Comment: I want the second one, but only up to a certain row. The array is 2D